# What is the $d/dt$ in the Schrödinger equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, schroedinger-equation, time, differentiation

I'm wondering, in the Schrödinger equation,
$$
{\displaystyle i\hbar {\frac {d}{dt}}\vert \Psi\rangle ={\hat {H}}\vert \Psi  }
$$
what is the $
{\displaystyle {\frac {d}{dt}}}
$ ? I understand it has to do with time, *t*, but I guess i'm hoping for some more understanding into what *d* is and how this derivative works, and what it means to the whole.

Comment: I've deleted some comments that responded impolitely to an earlier version of the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time derivative in Schrödinger equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/537687/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) We are in the Schrodinger picture. Physical states are labelled by a state vector $|\psi(t)\rangle$, which evolves in time as the state evolves in time. The time $t$ is a *parameter*-it labels different state configurations. This is a 'ket'-it stores all possible information about the system, at the time $t$.

2) We have, by definition, $$\frac{d}{dt}|\psi(t)\rangle\equiv \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{|\psi(t+\epsilon)\rangle-|\psi(t)\rangle}{\epsilon}$$  i.e. it's a measure of how different does the state look at $(t+dt)$ from $t$.

3) The schrodinger equation, then, is an equation that tells you the *CAUSAL time evolution* of the state of the system-if it were, so to speak, left to itself. It doesn't tell you what happens to the system when you *measure* it-that is a complicated issue. All it says is, if I specify what my system was in the beginning, $|\psi(0)\rangle$, I have here a first order equation that will allow me to predict what my system will be like at some $t$, i.e. I can solve this equation for $|\psi(t)\rangle$. And this is precisely the aim-predict how an initial state evolves.

4) It is crucial to note here that we only have a $d/dt$, and not also something like a $d/dx$ here. This is because the only parameter of the theory here is $t$-position $x$ etc come in as *dynamical variables* (i.e. evolve in time). There is a meaning to things like 'velocity=$dx/dt$'. Time is treated as SPECIAL, in both quantum and classical mechanics.

In QFT, which is relativistic by construction, *all $x,t$* are treated as parameters and not dynamical variables. This is a significant departure, and this is why the equations of motion there have all $4(3+1)$ derivatives. In this sense, regular QM is called $(0+1)$ dimensional QFT, with only one parameter-$t$.

The differential equation in $t$ now describes your physics.